# How to create dynamic UI based on json in iOS

Tags: ios, json, user-interface, dynamic

I have to create dynamic UI based on json like [Joshfire](https://github.com/joshfire/jsonform/wiki#getting-started).

Can anyone help me?

Comment: `git clone https://github.com/joshfire/jsonform.git`?

Comment: i want to make kind of joshfire because i can't use joshfire for iOS.

Comment: This is the wrong place to ask a question like that. SO is for specific programming questions, not generic cries for further education.

Comment: no, i mean i want to make dynamic UI which is generated based on JSON data.

Comment: I understood the question. It is a good question, but it is not appropriate for SO. You are not likely to find an answer here.

Comment: Do you have idea where i can find my solution?

Comment: Look at the Joshfire code and try to port it.

Comment: Ive been able to do this some years ago on Android, IOS, WP without any third-party code and it wasnt that difficult, just need to know how to parse and how to create the UI by code.

Answer (score 2):

Try jasonette. It’s like an all native aproach to build UI from json 
Site:  `http://jasonette.com/`
Github: `https://github.com/Jasonette/JASONETTE-iOS`

Comment: Just one thing to consider here. The original maintainer is no longer supporting the Jasonette project. There is a parallel project called Jasonelle (https://github.com/jasonelle/jasonette-ios) where they forked the project and planned to do new developments. But that is also kind of not very active.

So it might come down to owning a fork and implement the remaining feature yourself and then of course contribute back to community